# Unable to Change Record Type after Overriding with VF Page

Tags: visualforce, redirect, urlfor

I've overridden the 'Edit' button on a custom record with a Visualforce page and now I can't change the record type. It'll let me go to the 'Change' screen, click continue, but then the record type has been changed back.

I have no code referencing the record type at all on the page, in the controller, or any classes and triggers. This is what my page header looks like. The createOrEdit variable is just a string for either $Action.SFDC_MDF__c.edit or $Action.SFDC_MDF__c.new depending on whether I find a Fund Request Id.

```
<apex:page action="{!if($Profile.Name =='Partner - Reseller' || $Profile.Name=='Partner - Distributor',
                null, 
                urlFor(createOrEdit, $ObjectType.SFDC_MDF__c,
                [retURL=returnURL,id=myMDF.Id], true))}" 
        showHeader="true" sidebar="true" standardController="SFDC_MDF__c" extensions="FundRequestExtension" docType="HTML-5.0" title="Fund Request">
```

This has to be a bug or I'm not seeing something? Is this simply something that we have to deal with as a consequence for overriding standard buttons?

I've tried querying the recordType in the controller's constructor and can verify that it isn't being updated prior to the redirect.

Comment: The change screen does not set the value, it simply get the selected value and passes it as a URL parameter. If you controller is updating the record and not grabbing the selected record type from the URL parameter then the new record type will never be applied to the record

Comment: Thanks, Eric. That did it. I just grabbed the URL parameter in the controller and set it in the page parameters of the URLfor in the page action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change screen does not set the value, it simply get the selected value and passes it as a URL parameter. If you controller is updating the record and not grabbing the selected record type from the URL parameter then the new record type will never be applied to the record